# how to pass variable value as ID of documentGetElementByID

Tags: javascript, html

I have a 2D array and some numeric values, so I need to pass that value using document.getElementByID using id I'm going to set a class called highlight.

I'm corded nested loop to read array element and pass its value to document.getElementByID but the problem is I need to put a double or single quotes with the id. How do I put quotes with my array.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
  for ( var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
     document.getElementById('res[i][j]').className = ('highlight');
    }   
  }
```

Here I put array with quotes its wrong and nothing display. So how do I pass the id with this situation?

Comment: So you have numeric values in your 2D array and you want to convert them to string value to use them as ids in `getElementById()`? If it is the case, you can call like this: `document.getElementById('' + res[i][j]).className = ...`.

Comment: No i need to pass the numeric value as a id. Using that id im going to use styling purpose. For example id looks liks 1,1   1,2   1,3 like this.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you need quotes for because the actual id of a html element won't ever contain any quotes. Please add the res array to your question.

Comment: You don't need parenthesis then, as shown in the answer. You can do my trick just to be sure.

Comment: If i use without quote display a error className not be null

Comment: Note that your inner loop should probably be `for ( var j = 0; j < res[i].length; j++) {` (note **`[i]`** in `res[i].length`) if `res` is indeed a 2D Array.

Comment: Great.. i will try..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `.toString()`. It converts the attached number to a string.

```
for ( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
  for ( var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
     document.getElementById(res[i][j].toString()).className = ('highlight');
  }   
}
```

Comment: You also should pay heed to @Kaiido – your inner loop should probably be `j < res[i].length` not `j < res.length`.

Comment: after i convert it as a string error has been removed.. Thanks Man.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to quote the ID name. Take the class name out of the parentheses. See below:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) { 
  for ( var j = 0; j < res.length; j++) {
     document.getElementById(res[i][j]).className = 'highlight';
  }   
}
```

Comment if there's anything I missed.

Comment: If i use without quote there is error className not be null

Answer (score 0):

- Alternative code style to do the same
- Use '+=' instead of '='
- You sure you don't have a typo in the second loop? Perhaps it should use `res[i]` instead of `res`.

```
    res.forEach(res2 =>
      res2.forEach(item =>
        document.getElementById(item.toString()).className += ' highlight'));
```